Scripture Verse Regex
I've been trying to set up my own Scripture verse regex that can accomodate a wide ranges of Scripture types. I've copied some of this regex from another stackoverflow question. The issue that I'm having is that it won't find the verse after a comma, after a verse range as in Hos 10:1-3, 8. It will find Hos 10:1-3, but not 8. The issue boils down to a \S that I have in there, but I need that in there so that the regex will find scripture passages that are next to each other, where a second passage starts with a number, like 1 Peter. The regex is:
((?:(I+|1st|2nd|3rd|First|Second|Third|[123])\s)?(Gen|Ge|Gn|Exo|Ex|Exod|Lev|Le|Lv|Num|Nu|Nm|Nb|Deut|Dt|Josh|Jos|Jsh|Judg|Jdg|Jg|Jdgs|Rth|Ru|Sam|Samuel|Kings|Kgs|Kin|Chron|Chronicles|Ezra|Ezr|Ez|Neh|Ne|Esth|Es|Job|Job|Jb|Pslm|Ps|Psalms|Psa|Psm|Pss|Prov|Pr|Prv|Eccles|Ec|Song|So|Canticles|Song of Songs|SOS|Isa|Is|Jer|Je|Jr|Lam|La|Ezek|Eze|Ezk|Dan|Da|Dn|Hos|Ho|Joel|Joe|Jl|Amos|Am|Obad|Ob|Jnh|Jon|Micah|Mic|Nah|Na|Hab|Zeph|Zep|Zp|Haggai|Hag|Hg|Zech|Zec|Zc|Mal|Mal|Ml|Matt|Mt|Mrk|Mk|Mr|Luk|Lk|John|Jn|Jhn|Acts|Ac|Rom|Ro|Rm|Co|Cor|Corinthians|Gal|Ga|Ephes|Eph|Phil|Php|Col|Col|Th|Thes|Thess|Thessalonians|Ti|Tim|Timothy|Titus|Tit|Philem|Phm|Hebrews|Heb|He|James|Jas|Jm|Pe|Pet|Pt|Peter|Jn|Jo|Joh|Jhn|John|Jude|Jd|Jud|Jud|Rev|The Revelation|Genesis|Exodus|Leviticus|Numbers|Deuteronomy|Joshua|Judges|Ruth|Samuel|Kings|Chronicles|Ezra|Nehemiah|Esther|Job|Psalms|Psalm|Proverbs|Ecclesiastes|Song of Solomon|Isaiah|Jeremiah|Lamentations|Ezekiel|Daniel|Hosea|Joel|Amos|Obadiah|Jonah|Micah|Nahum|Habakkuk|Zephaniah|Haggai|Zechariah|Malachi|Matthew|Mark|Luke|John|Acts|Romans|Corinthians|Galatians|Ephesians|Philippians|Colossians|Thessalonians|Timothy|Titus|Philemon|Hebrews|James|Peter|John|Revelation|Re|Ap))(.?\s?\d+((?:[:.]\d+)?(\s?[-–—]\s?)?(?:\d+)(?:(,\s?\d+)*)?\S([:.]?\d+)?(,?\s?\d+[–—-]\s?\d+,?\d+)?)?(?:[:.]\d+)?(?:[abcde])?(?:,\d+)*(?:[-–—]\d?\s?)?)(?:[:.]\d+[–-—]\s?\d+,?\s?\d+)?
I have a link to the tester with a lot of the passages types that I'm wanting to find: link to regex tester with examples
Anyone have any suggestions on how to edit this in order to find Hos 10:1-3, 8? I'm pretty new to regex, so I suspect this should be an easy fix for a more seasoned regexer. I've tried quite a bit of different combinations with no success, as each new combination I've tried breaks finding the current passages that I've already been able to test.

How did you build this regex? It is very hard to read, and already has bugs (for example, it can match II Gen 28:30 and DeutX 28:30). You would probably have more luck writing it from bottom up.

Without knowing the full set of patterns you are trying to match I don’t see how we can help, because any suggestion made might break something that currently works for example.

I linked to my regex tester https://regex101.com/r/TqfbeW/1

If you want to match Hos 10:1-3, 8, you must also want to match Genesis 2:1 - 3:19, 1, but it seems you are fine with Genesis 2:1 - 3:19 - this is inconsistent. We can't help until you explain the rules.

Taking a simple case, how are we to parse Lk 1, 2 Peter. Are we safe to assume that Peter is always preceded by 1 or 2 (and similarly for all those names with multiple books). ie is the binding of the numeral before certain, known, book names stronger than any numeral possibly belonging to the preceding reference?

Given there is some sort of heirarchy/precedence here [you need to know that 1 Peter is a book and that the 1 cannot belong to the preceding reference] I would suggest coding this yourself e.g. in JavaScript rather than try to force regex into something it's not very good at. Is JS acceptable?

@WiktorStribiżew No, I don't want to match Genesis 2:1 - 3:19, 1 because the last 1 would constitute either the book the number of the next passage reference or it wouldn't make sense since the chapter ranges for Genesis are chapter 2 through 3, no resource would ever list chapter 1 after chapters 2 through 3.

@AHaworth Yes, we would assume that Peter would always have 1 or 2 in front of it. I definitely am open to coding it in JS rather than using the regex, I thought the regex would be quicker, but its proving to be very tricky for some more complex passage cases.

But we can't assume that John will always be preceded by a 1 or a 2 so I don't see how there can be a totally automatic way of parsing your syntax.

@AHaworth That's true, but I typically didn't have issues matching books with number prefixes in a string, but when trying to find situations like Hosea 2:1-3, 10, I would end up capturing John 3:16-17, 1 , when 1 Peter 1:1 came after it, which ends up lending credence to your point. I suppose it is not possible to have a regex to cover all these situations. Looks like needing to implement more JS is the way to go.

Whatever you use you will have to deal with the fact that there is an anomaly. Perhaps just tell the user that there are some Johns and get them to mend things afterwards.

There are a couple of problems with the regex approach.
One is that the book names can be of the form 2 Peter and this can get muddled with the introduced form like: Gen 1, 2 Peter.
For most of the books which can have numerals at the start this can be got round by adding these versions to the list of book names and looking for them explicitly before doing anything else.
However, this cannot solve the problem of John which can have a preceding numeral or not. No amount of clever parsing can get round this problem and the only person who can solve it is the one who authored the text and knows what they mean.
There is also the fact that a . can be used at the end of a book name, though this can also be accommodated by adding such strings to the list of book names before searching for them.
A major problem (IMO) is the difficulty of comprehending regexs which deal with these special cases. For maintainability I'd suggest coding in a less sophisticated way.
So, I gave up on regex because of the problems and instead here is a JS version - very unpolished and a bit hacky, but it does the job of dealing with the 2 Peter etc problems.
Authors will have to check themselves for the John problem but it's unlikely to occur often as the numbers after the preceding , would need to be low. Such a human check will be required however sophisticated and comprehensive the code/regex.


<style>
  span {
    background: pink;
  }
</style>
<div></div>
<script>
  const books = ['Gen', 'Ge', 'Gn', 'Exo', 'Ex', 'Exod', 'Lev', 'Le', 'Lv', 'Num', 'Nu', 'Nm', 'Nb', 'Deut', 'Dt', 'Josh', 'Jos', 'Jsh', 'Judg', 'Jdg', 'Jg', 'Jdgs', 'Rth', 'Ru', 'Sam', 'Samuel', 'Kings', 'Kgs', 'Kin', 'Chron', 'Chronicles', 'Ezra', 'Ezr', 'Ez', 'Neh', 'Ne', 'Esth', 'Es', 'Job', 'Job', 'Jb', 'Pslm', 'Ps', 'Psalms', 'Psa', 'Psm', 'Pss', 'Prov', 'Pr', 'Prv', 'Eccles', 'Ec', 'Song', 'So', 'Canticles', 'Song of Songs', 'SOS', 'Isa', 'Is', 'Jer', 'Je', 'Jr', 'Lam', 'La', 'Ezek', 'Eze', 'Ezk', 'Dan', 'Da', 'Dn', 'Hos', 'Ho', 'Joel', 'Joe', 'Jl', 'Amos', 'Am', 'Obad', 'Ob', 'Jnh', 'Jon', 'Micah', 'Mic', 'Nah', 'Na', 'Hab', 'Zeph', 'Zep', 'Zp', 'Haggai', 'Hag', 'Hg', 'Zech', 'Zec', 'Zc', 'Mal', 'Mal', 'Ml', 'Matt', 'Mt', 'Mrk', 'Mk', 'Mr', 'Luk', 'Lk', 'John', 'Jn', 'Jhn', 'Acts', 'Ac', 'Rom', 'Ro', 'Rm', 'Co', 'Cor', 'Corinthians', 'Gal', 'Ga', 'Ephes', 'Eph', 'Phil', 'Php', 'Col', 'Col', 'Th', 'Thes', 'Thess', 'Thessalonians', 'Ti', 'Tim', 'Timothy', 'Titus', 'Tit', 'Philem', 'Phm', 'Hebrews', 'Heb', 'He', 'James', 'Jas', 'Jm', 'Pe', 'Pet', 'Pt', 'Peter', 'Jn', 'Jo', 'Joh', 'Jhn', 'John', 'Jude', 'Jd', 'Jud', 'Jud', 'Rev', 'The Revelation', 'Genesis', 'Exodus', 'Leviticus', 'Numbers', 'Deuteronomy', 'Joshua', 'Judges', 'Ruth', 'Samuel', 'Kings', 'Chronicles', 'Ezra', 'Nehemiah', 'Esther', 'Job', 'Psalms', 'Psalm', 'Proverbs', 'Ecclesiastes', 'Song of Solomon', 'Isaiah', 'Jeremiah', 'Lamentations', 'Ezekiel', 'Daniel', 'Hosea', 'Joel', 'Amos', 'Obadiah', 'Jonah', 'Micah', 'Nahum', 'Habakkuk', 'Zephaniah', 'Haggai', 'Zechariah', 'Malachi', 'Matthew', 'Mark', 'Luke', 'John', 'Acts', 'Romans', 'Corinthians', 'Galatians', 'Ephesians', 'Philippians', 'Colossians', 'Thessalonians', 'Timothy', 'Titus', 'Philemon', 'Hebrews', 'James', 'Peter', 'John', 'Revelation', 'Re', 'Ap', 'Jd.', 'Heb.'];

  const preStrings = ['III', 'II', 'I', '1st', '2nd', '3rd', 'First', 'Second', 'Third', '1', '2', '3'];
  const preStringed = ['Sam', 'Samuel', 'Kings', 'Kgs', 'Kin', 'Chron', 'Chronicles', 'Corinthians', 'Co', 'Cor', 'Thessalonians', 'Th', 'Thes', 'Thess', 'Timothy', 'Ti', 'Tim', 'Peter', 'Pe', 'Pet', 'Pt', 'John', 'Jn', 'Jhn'];
  let text = `Joel 10:13 The passages Luke 2:32 and Lk 1:23 that we are looking at tonight 1 Cor 12:34 2 Cor 3:4 are found Jude 6, in Jude 5, Genesis 2:1 - 3:19, 1 John 3:16-17, 1 Peter 1:1, and Romans 10:13, 15, 17. Please turn in your Bibles. Ps 109:4,5,6,8.  Isaiah 61.2-3 Mt 5.4

Ge 27.27-29,89-40 Heb 11.20 Heb. 12.17 Jonah 3

Jd. 5
Jd 6

1 Cor 12:34 2 Cor 3:4. He 4.12 Re 1.16

Leviticus 16:6 He 5.3 He 7.27

Hos 10:1-3, 8 and 1 John 2:23`;
  //add the prestringed versions e.g. 1 Peter
  for (let b = 0; b < preStringed.length; b++) {
    for (let pre = 0; pre < preStrings.length; pre++) {
      books.push(preStrings[pre] + ' ' + preStringed[b]);
    }
  }
  // add the book name with . at the end as this seems to be added sometimes, at least to the shortened forms
  const length = books.length;
  for (let b = 0; b < length; b++) {
    books.push(books[b] + '.');
  }

  // sort descending - longer items first
  books.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
  let booksAt = [];
  // go thro' each book finding where it matches in text
  for (let b = 0; b < books.length; b++) {
    const book = books[b];
    let chNoInText = 0;
    while (chNoInText < text.length) {
      let j = text.indexOf(book, chNoInText);
      if (j < 0) break;
      if (((j + book.length) < text.length) && !(text.charAt(j + book.length).match(/^[a-z]+$/))) {
        booksAt.push([book, j]);
        let replacement = book;
        for (let k = 0; k < book.length; k++) {
          replacement = replacement.replace(book.charAt(k), 'X');
        }
        text = text.replace(book, replacement); // to prevent a shorter version matching
      }
      chNoInText = j + book.length + 1;
    }
  }
  // into ascending order of start position
  booksAt.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  newText = '';
  let chNoInText = 0;
  for (let b = 0; b < booksAt.length; b++) {
    while (chNoInText < booksAt[b][1]) { //copy across characters to start of book
      newText += text.charAt(chNoInText);
      chNoInText++;
    }
    newText += '<span>' + booksAt[b][0] + '</span><span>';
    chNoInText += booksAt[b][0].length; //skip the 'fill-in characters
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      chNoInText++;
      const nextCh = text.charAt(chNoInText);
      //test whether are at the end of the chapter(s) and verse(s)
      if (nextCh.match(/^[a-z]+$/)) break;
      if (nextCh.match(/^[A-Z]+$/)) break;
      newText += text.charAt(chNoInText - 1);
    };
    newText += '</span>&nbsp;';
  }
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = newText;
</script>




This looks pretty amazing to me, I'll plug this in and go with it from here. Thank so much!!

Yep, this looks like a great solution. Thanks again!

Running into an issue with this as mentioned in my comment below, this solution has trouble when finding both Genesis 1:1 and John 1:1. In currently finds Genesis 1 and 1 John 1:1. In this case, it would need to find John 1:1, as 1 John would not be prefixed with a colon, any ideas on a quick fix for this?

I will not comment on the part of the regex that matches the name or abbreviation of the book, but focus on the second part that matches the chapter(s) and verse(s):

It starts with (.?, but it looks like you want to match a literal point here, so it should be escaped: (\.?

You have constructs that could lead to exponential backtracking, like can be seen in this snippet: \d+)?(\s?[-–—]\s?)?(?:\d+. If that middle optional group does not capture any characters, you have \d+ followed by \d+, which means that if there is backtracking coming back to this part of the regex, the distribution of digits will change to every possible split. This should be avoided.

The \S cannot be right: this matches any non-space character, which could be punctuation, a letter, ... which surely would not be right to match there.

There is a lot of unnecessary repetition: Sometimes you have support for a certain pattern that is not supported elsewhere, like for instance the [abcde] suffix. This seems arbitrary. It is better to avoid such duplication where possible.


Now to the core of the question: how to avoid that a digit before a book name is captured as if it is a chapter/verse belonging to a preceding reference?
For this you can use a look-ahead. You could for instance assert before matching a space followed by digit as a chapter/verse, that these two characters are not followed by a space and a capital letter, as that would indicate that this digit is really a book number prefix.
Here is the suggested correction to that second part of your regex:
\.?\s(?:\d+[:.])?\d+[a-e]?(?:(?:\s?[-–—]|,)(?!\s[1-3]\s+[A-Z])\s?(?:\d+[:.])?\d+[a-e]?)*

Note however that there are ambiguities like this:

Jude 1, 2 John 1:5

...which could mean "(Jude 1), (2 John 1:5)" or "(Jude 1, 2) (John 1:5)". The suggested regex will take the first option. I would assume that in the second case you would better need some punctuation or text between the two references, like so:

Jude 1, 2; John 1:5

or so:

Jude 1, 2 and John 1:5


I was able to compose a regex that matches all of the examples in your regex101 link: https://regex101.com/r/J2Tpwz/2 - if you have a more complete list of the books that will be prefixed, you can add them to the section that currently looks like this John|Peter|Cor
The answer from @a-haworth seems very complete, and will most likely work across a large group of input texts. Just adding this one in case you need something purely regex-based
The regex shown at that link is:
/(?:\b\d+ )?[A-Z]\w+\.? [\d: .\-]+(?:, ?[\d\-]+)*(?<![ .])(?! (?:John|Peter|Cor))/g
and the breakdown is:

(?:\b\d+ )? - optionally match a leading number
[A-Z] - ensure the book name match begins with a capital letter
\w+\.? [\d: .\-]+ - a series of word characters, followed by an optional dot, space, then a sequence of numbers, colons, dots, and hyphens
(?:, ?[\d\-]+)* - an optional additional repeating sequence of a comma, optional space, and then sequence of digits and hyphens
(?<![ .]) - negative lookbehind to make sure the final group doesn't include a trailing space or period
(?! (?:John|Peter|Cor)) - negative lookahead to make sure that a final number match isn't immediately followed by a book name


I've been finding this regex quite useful. However, one issue that I've been noticing is that when you have two passages only separated by a single space like Genesis 1:1 John 1:1, it captures Genesis 1 and 1 John 1:1. Where in this instance it would be John 1:1, since 1 John would not start with the colon in front of it. So, I'm wondering how can we add, maybe, a negative look behind (?<!:) or something like that, to check if its attached to the colon of the previous reference. Does that make sense?

Glad to hear it's been useful - it's possible to add an additional condition at the end that checks to see that it only applies the negative lookahead if it wasn't immediately preceded by a colon followed by digits and optionally hyphens. HOWEVER regex101 errors on this because it doesn't like a quantifier inside the lookbehind, so whatever you're running this in may choke too. Here's the updated pattern in regexr https://regexr.com/83dte - it will show an error on initial load but if you delete a character and add it back, it will run

There may be a better way to do it (it's a slow regex this way and not ideal), I'll think on it but as a quick patch that should do what you want it to for now
